# Is it possible to fire a trigger directly from a class

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I am new to triggers but was wandering and couldn't find an answer after googling. Is it possible to fire a trigger from a class directly. I doesn't seem logical but was just wandering.

Comment: You can't call trigger but if you want to fire any trigger, just do any DML operation for that respective object in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger is called at specific times, creation/update/deletion.
If you trigger one of these events (defined in the trigger itself), the trigger will go off.

As Rohit suggested in the comments, you can trigger it from a class if you force an update on the record.

However, best practice would be to create a general method that can be called by both the trigger and the class.